distinguishing between alluvial fans and scree
I was at Lees Ferry (Arizona, USA) today and saw a lot of rock formations that looked like this:

As the picture shows there's what appears to be sand at a fairly constant angle all the way up to the rock wall.
My question is...  is this scree or is it an alluvial fan? And how do you tell the difference?

Scree is debris that has fallen from a steep face (i.e. a gravity driven mechanism), whereas alluvial fans are where the debris is deposited as the result of fluid action by water. You can also have colluvium, which is deposited by a number of methods including gravity and rain wash, but is characterized by a gentle slope above.
The characteristic of alluvial fans is that they will have at least one water channel, but often many channels, in them somewhere. The only way the alluvial fan spreads out is through the changing of these channels over time, leaving the characteristic fan. These fans all have a single starting point and would normally have a significant water flow at some points in the year (e.g. during melting snow cover, but not during summer or winter). They will usually have a single obvious channel above the head of the fan
Scree on the other hand tends to have less of a single point-source, it spreads out over an area and may appear to have many sources, where debris has been channeled by the landscape. They lack water courses or have water courses that are spread out (i.e. not from a single source).
In your photo I can see all three of these forms, as circled in the photo below. Scree slopes in the middle left (blue), just below the cliffs. An alluvial fan (white) below the water course that runs diagonally from the step on the right down towards the bottom left, and colluvial slopes (yellow) in the foreground with the sparse vegetation - these are more than just the bit circled in yellow, they are all the way along the foreground in that zone.
The allvial fan in this case is pretty indistinct, there should be a better one off to the bottom left of the photo, where the water course comes out.


Great answer! I was curious to see the difference myself!

Scree is plain to see on the upper levels of the rock formation (some of which has tumbled to a lower level). Scree is loose rock which has fallen.
But strata can be seen at all levels, so the lower levels are not scree. The entire outcrop may have been sedimentary at one time, but is now subject to erosion, and sand deposited by the wind.
